# Dynamically add to Ruby class method

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a plugin type thing for a 3rd party application.

With the application there is a class like so:

```
class foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  def random_properties
    @random_properties = nil
  end

  def self.thing_i_want_to_change
    %w(
      itemone
      itemtwo
    )
  end

end
```

And it also has a class like so:

```
class bar
  ARR_CONST = [ :otherstuff, :blah ]
end
```

I have been able to dynamically add to the array constant (from my plugin) using:

```
class bar
  ARR_CONST += [ :my_param ]
end
```

Is there a way I can add to the `foo.thing_i_want` array?

I was hoping to be able to do something similar for `foo.thing_i_want`, such as:

```
class foo
 def self.thing_i_want_to_change
   foo.thing_i_want_to_change + ["newitem"]
 end
end
```

But yeah that doesn't work

Comment: you should use class variable instead of constant since you want to change it.

Comment: The class with the constant is part of the application that I'm trying to create a plugin for. I'll try update the question so it makes more sense.

Comment: Class names **MUST** be capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand this question, but if you want to want to access `foo.thing_i_want` from `bar`, you need class inheritance of some kind:

```
class Bar < Foo
  ARR_CONST = [ :otherstuff, :blah ]
end
```

Then when you reopen the class later, it will maintain the inheritance:

```
rb(main):043:0> class Bar < Foo
irb(main):044:1> ARR_CONST = [ :otherstuff, :blah ]
irb(main):045:1> end
=> [:otherstuff, :blah]
irb(main):046:0> class Bar
irb(main):047:1> ARR_CONST += [ :my_param ]
irb(main):048:1> end
(irb):47: warning: already initialized constant Bar::ARR_CONST
(irb):44: warning: previous definition of ARR_CONST was here
=> [:otherstuff, :blah, :my_param]
irb(main):049:0> Bar.thing_i_want
=> ["itemone", "itemtwo"]
```

Although it is bad practice to add to modify a constant.

If you want to modify the `thing_i_want`, you can do this:

```
class Bar < Foo
  def self.thing_i_want
    super + ["itemthree"]
  end
end
```

With inheritance, the `super` call allows you access to the parent class' method of the same name, thus allowing you to modify what the parent class is doing.

Comment: Okay no that's not what I'm trying to do Lol ... I'll try make the question make more sense ...

Comment: Hmm looked promising ... Getting a syntax error: `syntax error, unexpected tOP_ASGN (SyntaxError)
2016-05-17_12:53:08.72894     super += ["itemthree"]`

Comment: Ahh, sorry, my brain typed it out differently than I meant.  No += because its not actually a variable.  I edited again, just get rid of the `=` and you'll be golden.

Comment: Hmm okay, yeah it's not a syntax error now, but it's not adding to the method as expected ... It's probably something to do with the application and the order it loads things ...

Answer (score 1):

To override a method in ruby, you can just reopen it after and redefine the method.

```
class Foo
    def say_hello
        puts "Hi"
    end
end

class Bar < Foo
    #Something
end

a = Bar.new
a.say_hello
# => Hi

class Bar
    def say_hello
        puts "Hello"
    end
end

a.say_hello
# => Hello
```

To add elements to the foo.thing_i_want, you can redefine entirely the method. Else, you can create an instance of Foo, get the initial array and return the updated array.

Comment: Just to throw a spanner in the works, I need it to still be referenced as `Foo` ... And it can't be a new instance of the class

Answer (score 1):

using [Module#alias_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-alias_method) enables you to redefine a new method, keeping the old behavior for reuse.

```
class Foo
  def self.thing_i_want_to_change
    %w(itemone itemtwo)
  end
end

class Foo
  singleton_class.send(:alias_method, 
                       :thing_i_wanted_to_change,
                       :thing_i_want_to_change)

  def self.thing_i_want_to_change
    thing_i_wanted_to_change << 'itemthree'
  end
end
```